# UrlRewrite to modify relative links

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Im running a site on MySQL/Apache/PHP and it contains a couple of pages and a top menu to help navigating between them.

In order to provide a spanish version of the site, I have created a subdirectory called /es and essentially copied the whole site and pasted it in that directory.

In a new htaccess file in this subdirectory, I would like an urlrewrite formula that modifies all relative links in this subdirectory. For example I want the link "/pages/about.html" to become "/es/pages/about.html". Essentially, I want "/es/" to be prepended to every relative url.

Is this possible? Is this a reasonable way to proceed when making new language variants of my site?

Comment: Are all your links currently written like `/foo/bar`, relative from the document root?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: Rewrite rules map external url patterns to internal ones. They won't rewrite your public urls.  Alternatively you could prepend all your urls, with a base url, that is based on the current language.  Or keep the paths, and create a new subdomain e.g. es.example.com for each language variant.

Comment: Yes a subdomain was my first thought, but it seems like the path variant is better from a SEO point of view. I will try to use a base url variable that is prepended before all relative urls as you suggest.